# Colorful and eyecandy text by Mathematica

Tags: text

I want to present my work somewhere and thus I made a Powerpoint presentation.
I am wondering if it is possible to make a colorful and stylish text by MMA. For example at the end of my presentation I write phrases such as "Thank you for your attention", "Questions?", or something similar.

For example would it be possible to create the below image by MMA and make each circle with the letter inside it move randomly or like a Sine wave. Could we add sparks of light around each moving circle.

[image]

Comment: Something like [that](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hibY9.png) can be easily done. It's all about `Style`.

Comment: Would it be possible that each letter was in a circle and the circles moves harmonically or randomly and they had flashes of light coming out of them.
This example might be too extreme! but I just wanted to give an idea.

Comment: "Stylish" and "colorful" (esp. in conjunction with "Powerpoint") may raise a few alarms for the seasoned typographer.

Comment: @YvesKlett "Powerpoint" raises a few alarms with or without "Stylish" or "colorful" :P

Comment: There is probably much fancier but if you want a sine wave: http://i.imgur.com/XWG1Aj1.gif

Comment: @Öskå now, Excel and stylish, that would raise at least DEFCON 2. I think Powerpoint is not a bad tool as such, but it is often used in a bad way. Sparks seem kind of borderline...

Comment: [too much?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/O2q56.gif)

Comment: I would not agree with downvoting, though. The question would benefit if the OP showed some previous effort, but quite probably we can expect some dazzling (um) and fun answers. And the intention to use *Mathematica* to generate graphics at all in the presence of PPT is commendable. @Öskå: why not post an answer?

Comment: @YvesKlett Because there are not circles, only some a simple wave. It's basically just `Style`..

Comment: @Öskå I think the OP would already benefit from that to get an idea how to go about modding text. However garish, thou shalt get an upvote from me, at least.

Comment: IMHO, I would say the speaker should bring the attention at the end to himself or herself.  Dim the last slide (e.g. gray @ 50% alpha) or a solid color/muted design; **say** "Thank you" etc.  If there is to be Q&A, then perhaps for the next slide, an outline of the talk; **say** "I would be pleased to take questions" etc.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I do so agree from an asthetic point of view, but at the same time I am kind of looking forward to some completely OTT answers ;-)

Comment: @YvesKlett I don't mean to dissuade people from answering.  I only meant to help the OP think about how to address the non *Mathematica* problem of making a good impression on the audience.

Comment: @MichaelE2, personally I like the last slide to contain just the word "APPLAUSE" :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some funky waves:

<sub>(The following can probably be neater but I'm just dropping the idea here)</sub>

```
DynamicModule[{a, b, imgs, drange, str, n = 6, export},
 drange[it_, d_] := Range[Pi/(d/it), Pi*it, Pi/(d/it)];
 str = ToUpperCase /@ StringSplit["This is some text!", ""];
 Panel@Column@{
    Row@{Slider[Dynamic[a], {-2, 2, .1}], Dynamic[a]},
    Row@{Slider[Dynamic[b], {-2, 2, .1}], Dynamic[b]},
    Row@{Slider[Dynamic[imgs], {3, 6}], Dynamic[imgs]},
    Dynamic@Row[Text@
         Style[#, #3, #2*20] & @@@ (Thread@{str, ((Sin[a*# + b] + 2) & /@ N@drange[n, Length@str]), 
          Hue[Length@str/#] & /@ Range@Length@str}), 
      ImageSize -> imgs*100],
    Dynamic@Plot[Sin[a*x + b], {x, 0, n*Pi}],
    Button["Export to GIF", export[a, imgs]]},
 Initialization :> (export[a_, imgs_] := Export["~/test.gif",
     Table[Row[Text@
          Style[#, #3, #2*20] & @@@ (Thread@{str, ((Sin[a*# + b] + 2) & /@ N@drange[n, Length@str]), 
           Hue[Length@str/#] & /@ Range@Length@str}), 
       ImageSize -> imgs*100], {b, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/20}], 
     "DisplayDurations" -> .1])]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

<sub>(And yes, the colours are ugly as well :D)</sub>

Clicking on `Export to GIF` results in:

[image]

By using `Framed[Style[#, #3, #2*20], RoundingRadius -> 100] &` as [Yves mentioned](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63304/colorful-and-eyecandy-text-by-mathematica/63314?noredirect=1#comment177947_63314) you can have the less fancy text on earth:

[image]

And without text:

> [image]

And with colours:

> [image]

Comment: And now for circles around each character try something along `Framed[Style[x], RoundingRadius -> 100]`. BTW, did you mean "ugly as well" or "ugly as hell"? :D

Comment: @YvesKlett That's totally not fancy :P http://i.stack.imgur.com/PtbcI.png The code is quite messy, and the code is quite ugly, so I guess I meant as well :D But it's ugly as hell indeed :(

Comment: Nah, neat is what it is... reminds me of the very hungry caterpillar! +1

Comment: @YvesKlett Now? I'm sure you love it!

Comment: I do! [drops off the chair felled by a bout of visually induced migraine]

Comment: I want to give vote +2 :D

Comment: @JunhoLee Probably because you head is still spinning due to the GIFs :D

Comment: Seems like you get to take over from @Hypnotoad.

Comment: @YvesKlett Thanks for introducing me to [Hypnotoad](http://r33b.net/). That's pretty weird :P

Answer (score 8):

Purely an extended comment, offered in the spirit of promoting clear communication.

From Edward Tufte's essay, [*The Cognitive Style of Powerpoint: Pitching Out Corrupts Within*](http://www.edwardtufte.com/tufte/powerpoint):

> In corporate and government bureaucracies, the standard method for
>   making a presentation is to talk about a list of points organized onto
>   slides projected up on the wall. For many years, overhead projectors
>   lit up transparencies, and slide projectors showed high-resolution
>   35mm slides. Now "slideware" computer programs for presentations are
>   nearly everywhere. Early in the 21st century, several hundred million
>   copies of Microsoft PowerPoint were turning out trillions of slides
>   each year.
>
> Alas, slideware often reduces the analytical quality of presentations.
>   In particular, the popular PowerPoint templates (ready-made designs)
>   usually weaken verbal and spatial reasoning, and almost always corrupt
>   statistical analysis. What is the problem with PowerPoint? And how can
>   we improve our presentations?

Also: 


[PowerPoint Does Rocket Science--and Better Techniques for Technical Reports](http://www.edwardtufte.com/bboard/q-and-a-fetch-msg?msg_id=0001yB)

[Lousy PowerPoint presentations: The fault of PP users?](http://www.edwardtufte.com/bboard/q-and-a-fetch-msg?msg_id=0002PP)

> The common defense of bad PowerPoint presentations is that they are the "fault of the user,
>   not the tool."
>
> This point raised by PP advocates in fact provokes a rich and complex
>   question about  nearly any type of expressive performance: What are
>   the causes of presentations?

[We Have Met the Enemy and He Is PowerPoint](http://www.nytimes.com/2010/04/27/world/27powerpoint.html)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. Especially this quote from your second link: It appears that many young engineers do not understand the need for, or know how to prepare, formal engineering documents such as reports, white papers, or analyses (Crippen, et al., "A.2, Observations" in Final Report of the Return to Flight Task Group, July 2005).